# Fusion table access from GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I guess this is 2 questions into one:

1. I have a Fusion table holding some data. I wrote a small web interface in GAS that allows to run queries on the fusion table and display the data returned.

   It worked fine with the old ClientLogin but now since that is deprecated it keeps giving me errors. Now for the life of me I cannot figure out how to setup the OAuth 2.0 to let the interface access the fusion table. I've been searching and searching and trying different things but it doesn't seem to be working. Why isn't there a straight forward library for GAS that can just do the whole authorization process for you without the need to code it manually?
2. Would there be a way to use only the Simple API access instead for accessing a Fusion Table?

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't there a straight forward library for GAS that can just do the whole authorization process for you without the need to code it manually?

There is! Take a look at this excellent [Fusion Tables Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/fusion-tables-class), which includes a function `doOAuth()` to set up the authorization for your script without making you write it all yourself.

> Would there be a way to use only the Simple API access...

OAuth only.

<sub><sup>PS: [This search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=apps%20script%20fusion%20table%20example) did the trick.</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes, I was using the FT Library you pointed but because it is using the OAuth 1.0 and Google is moving to OAuth 2.0 it has query restrictions plus it will be closed soon. This is actually the reason I'm trying to move my library to OAuth 2.0 but I can't seem to figure it out. Would anyone be able to modify the current library to use OAuth 2.0? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Kudos to you for being proactive - and sorry that I didn't fully understand your question! Maybe @james-ferreira would like to weigh in on whether the Fusion Tables Library will is due for an update?

Comment: Thanks, actually I would do it myself if I could figure out how to get the access token for OAuth 2.0 programmatically so I can replace the one for OAuth 1.0 in the existing FT Library. Once I have the token I managed to adapt the library to query the table and get the results. But I first need the token! :) Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!